# How to detect if a certain amount of time has passed in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a time stamp in a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
2011-02-23 20:39:49
```

How can I detect if a certain amount of time has passed since the creation of that timestamp. In other words if the timestamp was created on February 23, 2010 at 8:39:43 P.M. how can I detect if exactly 10 days (240 hours) have passed since the creation of this timestamp? How to do this in PHP?

Comment: Why not do it in SQL, MySQL can calculate dates much better than PHP can.

Comment: @AndreKR I guess doing it in MySQL is fine too, as long as the result is sent back to the PHP script. And by "result" I mean a simple yes it has been 10 days or no it has not.

Comment: You *definitely* want to do it in MySQL. What would you do otherwise? Select the entire table, read the entire table off slow hard drives, buffer the entire table into memory, send the entire table across a socket/pipe to PHP, buffer the entire table into memory there, then loop through every row and compare the dates? No, you just ask MySQL for the couple rows older than 10 days!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestampcol < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: +1 for subtracting 10 days from now, instead of adding 10 days to the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$isDone = time() - strtotime($row['time']) >= 240 * 3600;
```

Comment: Crikey. I was responding to "How to do this in PHP?" before the clarification. Take it easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
from foo
where date_field+interval 10 day >NOW()
```

Comment: It's better if you modify the right hand datetime instead of the field, since applying a function to the field means an index on it can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE_ADD(date_column, INTERVAL 10 DAY) > NOW()
```

This query will find any rows where the date_column contains a datetime value more than 10 days into the future from the current time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT the_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 240 HOUR AS more_than_240_hours_ago FROM table
```

Comment: If you mean 10 days, you can use `INTERVAL 10 DAY`.